# What means this mathematical notation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

Which members of the set this set contains?

[image]

I cannot understand these symbols like **≡** and **mod**.

Comment: `mod` is a short hand for modulus. $x \equiv y \pmod 4$ means $x - y$ is a multiple of $4$. see wiki entry of [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you really mean that you cannot understand the symbol $=$, or you meant that you cannot understand the symbol $\equiv$?  (If the latter, you should edit accordingly.)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner ≡ this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$B$ is the set of integers $x$ satisfying $x\equiv0\bmod4$, which means that $4|x$.

$B$ is thus the set of integers divisible by $4$ ($\{0,\pm4,\pm8,\pm12,...\}$).